# URDF parser: How to get a cylinder's dimensions

Tags: ros, urdf, collision

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have a question that is probably fairly basic.
I am parsing a .urdf robot model with the [URDF parser](https://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/diamondback/api/urdf/html/annotated.html). I am able to use this object to get info about my joints and links (masses, inertias etc).

I am now trying to get the length of a cylindrical link.
I have a pointer to the link in question:

```
boost::shared_ptr<const urdf::Link> link;
```

This link has a cylindrical collision element. I can confirm this by checking that

```
link->collision->geometry->type == urdf::Geometry::CYLINDER
```

In the URDF documentation, I see a `Cylinder` class that inherits from the `Geometry` class. This `Cylinder` class has the member data `length` that I am looking for.

The problem is that I don't know how to access it.

```
 link->collision->geometry->length
```

won't compile, as `link->collision->geometry` is of type `Geometry` and not `Cylinder`.

I tried casting the `boost::shared_ptr<urdf::Geometry>` to `boost::shared_ptr<urdf::Cylinder>`, but that, too, won't compile.

How can I access the `length` member?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196341/urdf-parser:-how-to-get-a-cylinder%27s-dimensions/) by [NickDP](https://answers.ros.org/users/20638/nickdp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2014-10-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I suffered from same problem.
I show you my solution by using pseudo code.

You can get pointer for a link by

```
#include <urdf/model.h>
urdf::Model model;
model.initParam(paramname);//Maybe you can use other init~ function.
boost::shared_ptr<const urdf::Link> link = model.getlink(linkname_on_urdf);
boost::shared_ptr<urdf::Cylinder> cylinder = 
boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<urdf::Cylinder>(link->visual->geometry);
```

you can access the length menber such as

```
double leng = cylinder->length;
```

This is my first posting.
Sorry if there are something improper.

---

Originally posted by [Shishimy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21938/shishimy/) with karma: 56 on 2015-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4